# Why does this sql select selects everything 3 times

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a homework where I need to display every employee together with his manager`s id (it needs to also display employees with no manager).
All of them are in a same table named employees. However when I run this command:

```
select first_name, last_name, manager_id
from employees
connect by prior employee_id = manager_id;
```

I get 269 rows, which makes no sense to me as there are only 93 employees.

I tried using select distinct which works for me, but I want to know why does this display 269 rows.  Also, is it possible to do this via recursive join somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT
    EMP.*, MGR.*
FROM
    EMPLOYEES EMP
    LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEES MGR
    ON MGR.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP.MANAGER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the manager id, then it is in the table.

I assume you want additional information about the manager.  If so, you want a `left join`:

```
select e.*, em.*
from employees e left join
     employees em
     on em.employee_id = m.manager_id;
```